# ActiveRecord on a legacy database with hundreds of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using activerecord to access an oracle database that has hundreds of fields.

Using find to get a record yields a huge amount of data. 98% of the time is spent sending data that is not required. Using #pluck helps to narrow it down, but plucking every single command seems not very elegant.

I think that a subclass that considers ONLY a small set of attributes is more efficient.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.... #has over 300 columns
end

class User_location < User
  fields: [:country, :city, :address, :zip ]
  ....
end

class User_demographics < User
  fields: [:eduaction_level, :religion, :age, :ethnicity]
  ....
end
```

The objective is that in a find, take or other method that returns records, instead of a "select *", a specific set of fields is used by default.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about `User.select('country, city').where( .... )` ?

Comment: Try `default_scope { select(:country, :city, :address, :zip) }`.